# Is there a way to generate screentips with images within Word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

In Word I'm looking to create a screentip which displays an image when the mouse is hovered over a word. I can't find a way to do this within Word's existing toolkit and can't generate a macro or add-in that can take the position of the mouse and return the word under it. I can't find anything online so thought I would ask here. Is it possible to do?

Comment: Have you seen this link? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_winother-mso_2010/how-can-i-create-a-hover-over-picture-in-microsoft/200e469d-ea49-4322-9f8c-6f823bc439d4  It's probably relevant to your question but I suspect it doesn't have the exact answer you're hoping for!

Comment: No, that is not possible.